# How to fix the "Corrupt Shape file '<shapefile>' encountered -- record size 218972988 is invalid" error in FME Workbench?

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, big-data

I have inherited a project where part of the workflow is the execution of numerous FME Workbench files.  It has worked flawlessly for several hundred runs, but it gets tripped up on a very large shapefile(actual shp is 1586981264 bytes, dbf is 51949349 bytes
`Type:                  Polygon

Number of Shapes:      775361`   ).

`Corrupt Shape file '<shapefilepath>' encountered -- record size 218972988 is invalid`

ArcCatalog and shpinfo.exe have no trouble with it.

Based on some google searches, I think the issue is with the size of the shapefile but this might be outdated information:
http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/fme/conversations/topics/3031
http://evangelism.safe.com/tag/google/

Is there a way to configure FME to allow for larger shapefiles?

**FME Information:**
Edition: FME Professional Edition (node locked-crc)
Version: FME(R) 2012 SP2 (20120417 - Build 12238 - WIN64)

**OS:**
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              8 Processor(s) Installed.

Intel64 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2 GenuineIntel ~3325 Mhz * 6
Total Physical Memory:     31,996 MB

Comment: 800 million features?  I can't think of any way to store that in shapefile format -- the limit is 2^31-1 short words in the .shp file *or* 2^31-1 *bytes* in the .dbf (which would limit you to ~533M 4-byte integers).  Can you provide exact file sizes for the .shp and .dbf, and a description of the dBase attributes (formatted width is key)?

Comment: shapefilerepairer http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=10806

Comment: @Vince: I forgot to remove some zeros (or omit the `K`).  Updated question w/ actual counts/sizes. Definitely not 800 million!

Comment: Is using arcmap to do 'shape to file-geodatabase' out the question? Then running the workspace with that? - It must be hitting a limit in the Reader.

Comment: The 'shpinfo' utility in an ArcSDE install would report if the file is actually corrupt. You're not anywhere near the shapefile limitations (unless the dBase record size is *huge*), so this is likely an application limit.

Comment: arcmap can display the file correctly and it is fme saying it is coruupt?

Comment: @Mapperz: I'm trying that now and it seems to be cranking along...

Comment: @BradNesom: that is correct.  ArcCatalog/ArcMap can read/display the shapefile. I was able to move it into a FGDB this earlier this morning (which I'm using for @Mapperz suggestion). I tried QGIS, but it crashed.  A  `shpinfo.exe -o describe` also works.

Comment: I've asked around at Safe HQ to see if anyone knows what the message is. But we might have to get a copy of your data to know what the exact issue is. Hopefully not. I'll let you know what our developers say.

Comment: @Jay If the data is sensitve, se_toolkit can be used to generate large shapefiles with random data of a similar size (w.r.t. rows and vertices/shape and dBase attribute width).

Comment: @Mapperz: update on the FGDB test: the translate finished successfully, but I haven't a done careful check yet...but so far it looks good.  It would still take a bit of work to sew this in to the current workflow...so I'll hold out for a SAFE Support fix. But I think that would be a useful answer to this question--I'll +1 it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like a fault in FME. It is related to content size, but not in a way I think you can workaround.

I've filed a problem report with the developers and it does appear a relatively simple fix. If you're able to supply a copy of the data then please report the issue via safe.com/support, referencing PR#48195 and making the data available (you can upload it to ftp.safe.com/incoming) - though hopefully we can fix the issue without it.

> **looks like we have the data and the issue is fixed in FME2014 (build
>   14167 or greater)**.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I submitted a problem report, but forgot to reference PR#48195. I replied to support email, but not sure if that will attach it to the support ticket.  `C81210 - Safe Software Support Ticket Created [ ref:_00D30ePES._500a0ZorcF:ref ]`

Comment: Hi Jay - looks like we have the data and the issue is fixed in FME2014 (build 14167 or greater). So it should all be OK, but give us a shout if you still have problems.

Comment: I am using FME2014 build 14168 and I think it is safe to say that I'm past the shapefile issue (36 hours and still running...).

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would do in this situation is.

In ArcMap load the large shapefile and convert this into a file-geodatabase.
Why? The structure of the file geodatabase has been created by ESRI not by choice but because they had to - larger and larger files impacted on the shapefile (2GB limit at the time) and also the access/personal geodatabase (.mdb) has poor stability at nearly capacity (2GB).

So moving to the shapefile to the File Geodatabase should see the (ArcObjects) reader in FME have no issues reading the geometry. Yes is more work to include the File Geodatabase into FME. But a time-saver when you think of how much time you have already used in trying to convert the shapefile directly.

Not a perfect solution more of a work-around.